# Org-mode not exporting frames correctly using beamer

Tags: org-mode, latex, beamer

I'm writing a presentation using Org-mode and beamer. The problem is that all the frames are putted into a single one. I have the following code:

```
#+TITLE: \textbf{example}
#+AUTHOR: \large{sdjfioa}
#+DATE:
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation,smaller]
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usetheme{Ilmenau}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usecolortheme{beaver}
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:nil title:nil
* This is the first structural section

** This should be a frame
but it is not

** This should be another frame
fajsiodjfoiasjdfoii
```

the exported .tex file contains the following:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{This is the first structural section}
\label{sec:org7d325e6}

\subsection{This should be a frame}
\label{sec:org5055c4a}
but it is not


\subsection{This should be another frame}
\label{sec:orgcbe0add}
fajsiodjfoiasjdfoii
\end{document}
```

And the pdf is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQYuU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands to export a beamer document to a {buffer, file, PDF file, PDF file and Open} are different from the normal LaTeX export commands:

- `C-c C-e l B`  exports to a LaTeX beamer buffer.
- `C-c C-e l b`  exports to a LaTeX beamer file.
- `C-c C-e l P`  exports to a PDF file.
- `C-c C-e l O`  exports to a PDF file and opens the file.

N.B. That's a CAPITAL P for exporting to PDF and a CAPITAL O for exporting to PDF and opening the file. Make sure that you use the correct command.

Comment: Yes I use those commands to export, specifically the last two.

Comment: Are you sure, you are using CAPITAL P and CAPITAL O? Your tex file does not show any evidence of that. Mine e.g. says `\begin{frame}[label={sec:orge8610a5}]{This should be a frame}
but it is not
\end{frame}`

Comment: Now that i look closer, you used a capital p and o, I don't have those options when opening the export menù with C-c C-e. Running `org-beamer-export-to-pdf` works though.

Comment: You should not have to do this, but try `(load-library 'ox-beamer)` and see if the options appear in the menu.

Comment: Yes, using that command worked. Now the other options show up. Thank you!

Comment: There is still the problem of why that does not happen automatically, but that is a different problem. But I'm glad the original problem is sorted.